# Can I not make provider viewmodel a singleton?

Tags: flutter

I have a provider view model that I am defining as singleton like this:

```dart
class LoginProvider extends BaseModel {
  LoginProvider._();
  static LoginProvider _instance = LoginProvider._();
  factory LoginProvider()=>_instance;
}
```

I know that provider itself maintains the view models as singletons. But is it wrong if I do this? I am doing this just so that I can access it just by writing `LoginProvider()` instead of writing whole `Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context)`. It makes me able to executive one time functions in `initState` also. But some colleagues think that it is a bad practice. May I know why?

Comment: Provider does _not_ use singletons and doesn't want to.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I was hoping you would answer. So it is not wrong if I use it like this?

Comment: It is. You're free to do so, but provider voluntarily doesn't rely on globals/singletons. Using them is usually anti-pattern

Comment: okay... so its all about following a pattern....thanks....